# How to incrementally assign variable names using numbers inside a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I have a simple code where I want to update the variable names as follows:

```
n = 5

for i in range(0, n):
    train_fold_[i], val_fold_[i] = result[i][0],result[i][1]
```

I want the above code to generate a total of 10 variables with names train_fold_0, val_fold_0, train_fold_1, val_fold_1,......, train_fold_4, val_fold_4.

However, when I run this code, it is only generating 2 variables as follows: train_fold_i, val_fold_i.

I know this is extremely simple, but can someone please help me out with this as I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: Usually you would use a data structure in this case (probably a list). Why do you want to have 10 different variables?

Comment: Do `train_fold, val_fold = zip(*[result[i] for i in range(n)])`.  You can now access your ten values as `train_fold[0]`, `val_fold[0]`, `train_fold[1]`, etc.

Comment: If `n == len(result)` you can do it more simply: `train_fold, val_fold = zip(*result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exec`

```
n = 5

for i in range(0, n):
    value1, value2 = i, i+1
    exec(f'train_fold_{i}, val_fold_{i} = {value1}, {value2}')
```

then

```
print(train_fold_3, val_fold_3)
>>> 3 4
```